# How to use ReactiveList in C# in 4.5.2 .Net version

Tags: c#, list

I am using .Net 4.5.2 framework. Here I have a list of Hospital (List). Hospital model has the following attributes.

- HospitalId
- HospitalName
- DepartmentId

In my C# application, there is a functionality to edit hospital list. Change the hospital name, add new hospital, remove hospital, add the department to the hospital, remove departments from the hospital.

Where I want to check whether the list has been changed before going to save the details to the database. As I go through, there is a special type of list in C# named 'ReactiveList'. Using Reactive List, It is very easy to track the changes in a list. But the problem is I couldn't use ReactiveList in C# since ReactiveList package is not available with the .Net version 4.5.2 which is used by myself.

Is there any solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: If the library isn't available for 4.5.2, then you'll have to upgrade framework versions to one that *is* supported.

Comment: .. or alternatively look for an older version of the package that does support 4.5.2

Comment: The earliest version available to me in Nuget is 8.0.0, which is built on .Net Framework 4.6.1.  Only four releases are listed.  Older releases are available from Github, but no framework versions are listed in their release notes.

Comment: If the package is open source, you could look at how they've implemented the features, or simply create your own build targeting 4.5.2 (assuming it isn't using new features in 4.6)

Comment: library is available for downward version of .Net framewrok.